# How to Order a sequence in SQL in ASC order

Tags: sql, oracle

I was looking to find out how i can order a sequence in SQL in order to remove any duplicate values.

For example if i have the following data set:

```
Set_of_skills
ABC/DEF/GHI
DEF/GHI/ABC
GHI/ABC/DEF
```

and I ran the following query:

```
SELECT distinct set_of_skills FROM Table1;
```

This will bring back all of these rows which I understand but what I would like to do is order the skills in ascending order as this will give me the following:

```
Set_of_skills_1
ABC/DEF/GHI
ABC/DEF/GHI
ABC/DEF/GHI
```

Now if i was to run a distinct query this would tell me that all of these actually are the same skill rather than 3 different ones.

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise on how i can achieve this, would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

---

Update:

As i have a table with the data normalized, so if the data in my table is like the following:

```
AGENT_ID | Set_of_skills
1 | ABC
1 | DEF
1 | GHI
2 | DEF
2 | GHI
2 | ABC
3 | GHI
3 | ABC
3 | DEF
```

Is it a case of ordering the skills column and then putting it into a string so that I can then determine the exact Distinct skills that I have across the team?

Comment: Does the skills column really have the string `ABC/DEF/GHI` ?  If so, you should seriously consider normalizing your table data.

Comment: Any particular reason you choose to violate normalization rules in your SQL database?

Comment: [ORDER BY](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/SELECT.htm#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2168299)?

Comment: Fix you data structure so you have one row per whatever and per skill.  Storing multiple values in a string column is just a bad idea.  And now you are learning why.

Comment: Hi, the skillset is available per row within another table so for example I have the agent id (repeated) and then all their skills per row. The table i am looking at shows 1 agent and all their skills in one row separated by /

Comment: How would i achieve the ordering with all the skills in each row to determine the exact skillset differences?

Comment: So are you actually looking at a table with redundant/ data, or a view that does string aggregation (e.g. with l`istagg`)? Either way you'll find this easier if you look at the table that has one row per skill.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick solution using regular expressions, a hierarchical query, and `listagg()`. With that said, you should really fix your data model.

For example, you could use the inner query (without the outer one) to simply normalize your current data.

```
with
     test_data ( Set_of_skills ) as (
       select 'ABC/DEF/GHI' from dual union all
       select 'DEF/GHI/ABC' from dual union all
       select 'GHI/ABC/DEF' from dual
     )
--   end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select set_of_skills,
       listagg(token, '/') within group (order by token) as ordered_set_of_skills
from   ( select set_of_skills, 
                regexp_substr(set_of_skills || '/', '([^/]*)/', 1, level, null, 1) as token
         from   test_data
         connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(set_of_skills, '/')
                and prior set_of_skills = set_of_skills
                and prior sys_guid() is not null
       )
group by set_of_skills
;

SET_OF_SKILLS        ORDERED_SET_OF_SKILLS
-------------------- -----------------------
ABC/DEF/GHI          ABC/DEF/GHI
DEF/GHI/ABC          ABC/DEF/GHI
GHI/ABC/DEF          ABC/DEF/GHI

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Excellent solution Math Guy, yours is much cleaner that the brute force mess I came up with. I am saving this as a coding example to use in the future when I am given problems like this.